# Terraform Azure Key Vault Secret does not depend_on access_policy

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, azure-rm

Applying the below configuration works fine - the resources gets setup and my user gets the access policy set up for the key vault, and access policy to read the secret(s).

But when another developer tries the same script, it fails with error:

```
Error: making Read request on Azure KeyVault Secret secret: keyvault.BaseClient#GetSecret: Failure responding to request: StatusCo
de=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or applicat
ion 'appid=(appid);oid=(aad user oid);numgroups=xx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/1aa
sa4/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'kvexample'. For help resol
ving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287" InnerError={"code":"AccessDenied"}
```

I thought that `depends_on` will make sure that the `access_policy` gets setup prior to reading the secrets, but evidently not. Terraform tries to read the secrets when `terraform plan` *before* `access_policy` is setup.

How can I solve this?

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                       = "kvexample"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 90
  purge_protection_enabled   = false

  sku_name = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "user" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  # oid is my aad user oid

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get",
    "Set",
    "List",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  name         = "secretname"
  value        = "secretvalue"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id

  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.user]
}
```

Edit:

I have also tried setting the access policy directly in keyvault, but I get the same error.

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                       = "kvexample"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 90
  purge_protection_enabled   = false

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
      tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
      # oid is my aad user oid

      secret_permissions = [
        "Get",
        "Set",
        "List",
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So the first time you ran it it was ok ? Maybe configure a group and it should be fine (more a workaround tho).

Comment: Yes, the first time it ran ok. As long as the secret is not already created or you already have permission to read it, it works fine. Thanks for the tip about the group, that is a good workaround that might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Key Vault access policy block inside `azurerm_key_vault` resource and avoid using depends_on in resource `azurerm_key_vault_secret`

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                       = "kvexample"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 90
  purge_protection_enabled   = false

  sku_name = "standard"
  
  access_policy {
    tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    secret_permissions = [
      "Set",
      "Get",
      "List"
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  name         = "secretname"
  value        = "secretvalue"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem, unfortunately. It still fails if the `object_id` is different than the first which deployed the key vault.

Comment: Can you use object id that deployed key vault originally?

Comment: That object_id stems from `data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id`, which is whoever's logged in. If the `key_vault_secret` is already applied, and another object_id runs this, it will fail on permission error on that secret. I want this terraform to be able to be run by another developer.

Comment: I agree with @Thomas to configure a group access instead of user access in KeyVault policy